# Copy file from oneDrive shared url to my server using PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

My client will share the file form one drive , my php laravel application should copy the file from OneDrive to our server using that shared url.. How I can do that in php?

I tried by below code :

```
    $fileurl = "https://sindionsa-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/yasser_sindion_com/Edk_7pdslBdKppoCxC_l2BwB7MpYL5k_Y4r94HC2SYTZCw?e=RTjVqh";
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            "http" => array(
                "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
            )
        )
    );
    $drive_file = file_get_contents($fileurl,false, $context);
    $pdf_filename_2 = substr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", mt_rand(0, 51), 1).substr(md5(time()), 1);
    $save_attachment_file_8 = public_path($pdf_filename_2.'.pdf');
    
    
    file_put_contents($save_attachment_file_8, $drive_file);
    echo "done";die;
```

My code has created a pdf file .. But It couldn't copy peroperly.. It showing error while open the file.

Comment: Is that URL just publicly accessible? If so then you can download it like any regular file, using file_get_contents, or some php client like Guzzle, or any other option.

Comment: Yes .. it was public access url .. I tried to access via file_get_contents .. But it return Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: https://sindionsa-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/yasser_sindion_com/Edk_7pdslBdKppoCxC_l2BwBVDJYaHC-ELD2NEecFU_yhQ?e=a9Tf6l

Comment: I see the problem. This link doesn't open the file directly, but opens a web-page. Ask your client to use "Embed" button on OneDrive. It will generate a direct link to the file and you'll be able to download it with file_get_contents.

Comment: Sorry really I couldn't find the option "Embed".. It showing the option in copy, download etc.. I tried in view online on OneDrive..

Comment: No you won't find it. Only the owner of the file can generate a link for embedding.

Comment: I logged in as owner of the file account.. Still I couldn't find that.. Please let me know where I can find "Embed" option ..

Comment: When I open any file in OneDrive there is a topbar with Embed button in the middle: https://image.prntscr.com/image/SvjeyAIZRSKbPbIsBINAMg.png

Comment: Embed code url as well dosn't work ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.